# Determine if it is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have problems with exercise

Determine which of the following binary operations is associative:

The operation $\cdot$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $a\cdot b = \displaystyle \frac{a+b}{5}$

I have to prove that $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$

$(a*b)*c= (\displaystyle \frac{a+b}{5}) *c $
$= \displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{5}+c}{5}$

How can I continue?

Thanks

Comment: By doing the remaining computations, I guess.

Comment: Computing $(a\ast b) \ast c$ and $a \ast(b\ast c)$ according to José so check if they are equal.

Comment: How you proceed depends on what you think the answer is. Do you think it's associative? If so, then try expanding the right hand side the same way, and manipulating the expressions until they're clearly equal. Do you think it's not associative? Then try substituting three of your favourite rational numbers in for $a, b, c$, and keep doing so until $(a * b) * c$ and $a * (b * c)$ are different numbers. Actually, even if you think it is associative, it's probably not a bad idea to try some examples of $a, b, c$, and see if they satisfy the equation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the binary operation is not associative.

$(a*b)*c= (\displaystyle \frac{a+b}{5}) *c $
$= \displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{5}+c}{5}$

can be simplified as $(a+b+5c)/25$

while $a*(b*c)= (5a+b+c)/25$

Comment: ok i understand thank you very much

Comment: Make sure next time  asking new qns. onwards, you try on your own as the problem was quite simple else you may face downvotes, nd mark answer as accepted to close the problem.